# Spring Data JPA persistent object not updating

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, spring-data

I have an issue with updating persistent objects.  I have two objects "Admission" and "Location" as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Admissions")
public class Admission implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false) 
    @JoinColumn(name="DemographicId", unique = true, nullable=false)
    private Demographic demographic;

    @OneToOne(optional=false) 
    @JoinColumn(name="VisitId", unique = true, nullable=false)
    private Visit visit;

    @OneToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="LocationId", nullable=false)
    private Location location;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "Updated", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private Date updated;  



@Entity
@Table(name = "Locations")
public class Location implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name="FacilityId", nullable=true)
    private Facility facility;

    @JoinColumn(name="WardId", nullable=true)
    private Ward ward;

    @JoinColumn(name="RoomId", nullable=true)
    private Room room;

    @JoinColumn(name="BedId", nullable=true)
    private Bed bed;
```

If I create an Admission and save it, all is well.  If I then retrieve the Admission Update the Location to a new Location object the Admission does not save/update.  The code I am using to save is:

```
public void transfer(MSH msh, PV1 pv1, PV2 pv2) {
    String visitNumber = pv1.getVisitNumber().getIDNumber().getValue();
    Visit myVisit = visitService.findByVisitNumber(visitNumber); 

    if (myVisit == null) { 
        log.debug("Unable to transfer if we have no Visit");
        return;
    }

    Admission myAdmission = admissionService.findByVisit(myVisit);
    myAdmission.setLocation(getLocation(msh, pv1));
}
```

I have tried doing a final save and flush (which does not seem to work), but understand that this should not be necessary.

An example of my service class

```
@Service
public class LocationServiceImpl implements LocationService {

    @Resource
    private LocationRepository repository;

    @Transactional
    public Location create(Location location) {
        Location created = location;
        return unique(created);
    }

    @Transactional
    public Location findByLocation(Location location) {
        return repository.findByLocation(location.getFacility(),
                location.getWard(), location.getRoom(), location.getBed());
    }

    @Transactional
    private Location unique(Location location) {
        Location found = findByLocation(location);

        if (found == null) {
            return repository.save(location);
        }
        return found;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that

```
public void transfer(MSH msh, PV1 pv1, PV2 pv2) {
```

Is not being executed within a transaction, please add **@Transactional** to your service class.

Comment: Thank you for this.  You have just solved a bunch of issues in a single shot!  In summary, any method that updates data objects needs to be set as @Transactional - is that correct?

Comment: that is correct my friend, once the method end transaction are commit, but you must have an open an valid transaction to update the data. If you are only searching transaction is not required